# Why my web page with .mp3 files works on laptop and phone but not ipad

Tags: audio, ipad, mobile-website

My website has a list of tunes with audio tags that call .mp3 files stored in a folder that is in the same folder as the index.html file. The audio tags work fine on my laptop and iphone, but do not seem to load on my ipad, Any ideas would be very welcome!

Here's the url to the website:
https://barb-elliott.github.io/TuneList/

Tried opening the site on laptop, iphone, and ipad. Expected the audio files to load and be playable from all three, but they don't work on the ipad,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What does your code look like?

Comment: <table id="myTable">          
         <th id="Mp3Heading">Mp3</th>
          <td>
               <audio class="myAudio" controls>
                  <source src="Music/Acrobat's New Trick.mp3">
               </audio> (with much more and end tags)

Comment: Please include that in your post and not in the comments.  Also explain what you mean by 'they don't work on the ipad'.  They don't render? They don't play?

Comment: Do you get any messages in the javascript console on the iPad?

Comment: My ipad is running ios 17.1.1 and I don't have Developer Mode, which seems to make it impossible for me to see the javascript console. If there IS a way you know of, please let me know!

Comment: ewokx, I made some change and now the only problem is that now there is text on the rendered html audio element that says "Error" even though they do play.

Comment: You should be able to connect your iPad in via cable to laptop and launch safari on your mac / PC and [see the console from there](https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798). I believe Chrome for iPad will also allow you to see a developer console and there. There is also projects like [eruda](https://github.com/liriliri/eruda). I would say your first goal here would be to see a console, otherwise you are flying blind. After that, minimise the website. Can you load _**1**_ item on your playlist?

Comment: If you start removing elements from your webpage, is there a point where things star to function? What have you tried so far in terms of debugging?

Comment: I tried connecting the iPad, but the player looks fine in that view... no Error text and no airplay icon. What I did, FYI, is I connected the iPad with Web Inspector enabled (on both the Mac and iPad), opened Safari > Develop>my iPad, typed my website in the address line. I'll try the other methods you've suggested tonight. Haven't tried deleting elements, but I'll try that to. Any info on how that might cause the issues would be nice to hear!

Comment: With respect to web development, what is important to keep in mind is that it is as close to the Wild West as programming gets. When you factor in multiple browsers, across multiple versions, across multiple OSs each of which with their own implementation of how to deal with what is being given to them in terms of HTML / CSS as well as JavaScript being a language that is constantly updated and ready to introduce breaking changes at any point. Fault finding of this kind is not _part_ of the job, it  _**is**_ the job. Having the kind of problems you are having are entirely normal.